# transformed color space in matlab

Tags: matlab

The transformed color space (R’, G’, B’) is defined as follows:

```
R' = R-mean(R)/sd(R),    
G' = R-mean(G)/sd(G),    
B' = R-mean(B)/sd(B),
```

Where `mean` and `sd(standard deviation)` of color channels C computed over whole image where C which belongs to (R,G,B).

I have to apply transformed color space to find the relationship b/w the pair of sampled points.

Suppose `P(i)Cm` are the values of color channel cm which belongs to (R’, G’, B’) of the sampled point cm and `P(j)Cn` are the values of color channel `cn` which belongs to (R’, G’, B’) of the sampled point `cn` where `p(i)=(xi,yi)` and `p(j)=(xj,yj)`

```
if P(i)Cm < P(j)Cn  

then 1

 else 0
```

Where `cm` and `cn` can be `(R',R')(R',G'),(R',B'),(G',G'),(G',B')(B',B')`

Answer (score 0):

To do the transformation, you can:

```
rgb_img = double(rgb_img); %// convert to double
mu = mean( reshape(rgb_img,[],3), 1 ); %// get mean of each channel
sd = std( reshape(rgb_img,[],3), 0, 1); %// get std of each channel
img_transformed = bsxfun( @rdivide, ...
       bsxfun( @minus, rgb_img, permute(mu,[1 3 2]) ),
       permute(sd, [1 3 2]) );
```

Once you transformed your image, you can access the pixel values

```
img_transformed( yi, xi, ci )
```

Is the transformed value of channel `ci` in location `(xi, yi)`

Comment: how can i compare pi =(xi,yi) in cm and pj = (xj,yj) in cn where (cm,cn) is (R',R')

Comment: @nidhi I edited my answer. I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Error using var (line 59)
First argument must be single or double.

Error in std (line 32)
y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));

Comment: how can I access the values of R' channel can u please give example  

                                                                                                             img_transformed( yi, xi, R' )<img_transformed( yj, xj, R' )

Comment: @nidhi, your `rgb_img` is of type `uint8` and therefore `std` function is having a little trouble with it. convert it to `double` by: `rgb_img=double(rgb_img);` before you transform it.

Comment: @nidhi regarding accessing `R'`, the channel index (`ci` in my answer) of the red channel is 1 thus: `img_transformed( yi, xi, 1 )<img_transformed( yj, xj, 1)` checks for the `R'` values of pixels `i` and `j`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @shai now i am getting following error     Error using bsxfun
Mixed integer class inputs are not supported.

Comment: @nidhi have you converted `rgb_img` to `double`?

Comment: thankyou so much @shai                                                                                                               as the channels (R',R') are same so xi,yi would be equal to Xj,yj den how the comparision can be done here??

Comment: @nidhi the location `(xi,yi)` is suppose to be different than `(xj,yj)`.

Comment: but the channel is same so the points would also be same in case of (R',R')

Comment: hi shai, I have used the above code for finding out the transformations of RGB channels after that I also have made blocks of a image , I understand the both points are different,now the main question is that I have to find the relation between pixels in (R',R') as described above for distinguish foreground and background pls help m hereby attaching my code

Comment: @nidhi do not post code in comment - nobody can read it. If you have an update, you can edit your question. If this is a new question - post it as such.